# Income present but no tax residence. What then?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, law, tax-residency

Many countries have this 187 days rule: if you’ve lived and worked for more than 187 days in that country you’re automatically a tax resident there. But what if you change countries frequently, let’s say every 2-3 months? Many professions can easily handle that (writers, bloggers, web designers, software developers, etc.)  and I know of people who have been living like that for over 5 years.

Just to clarify: I am not talking about the situation when one owns a house in their home country, or they have left their wife with kids there and work abroad. I am talking about people whose all belongings are passport, laptop and two travel bags.

Where are they supposed to pay taxes on their legal income?

Answer (score 3):

Every country has their own rules, and some (like the US) require tax filing and paying for global income from their citizens, no matter where you live or work.

So check with the country of your citizenship(s), and the countries you lived in while getting income, and you might be liable to pay taxes in one, two, many, all, or none of them. There is no generic answer that catches all situations, as countries are not required to agree on their laws and policies.

Comment: " some (like the US) require tax filing and paying for global income from their citizens, no matter where you live or work" The US is pretty much the only significant country that does this.

Comment: Thanks, @user84385 . If you would have qualified your question with your country and which countries you are talking about, I could have been more specific. But why would you care.

Comment: Actually it is not "some countries". it is basically the USA. Period. No over industrialized countries taxes non residents for out of state income even if they are out of the state for long term. I think there is one more country that tries it, and it is some third world country.

Comment: Good to know that Money SE is only for use by people in industrialised countries, then.  If it isn't, those comments are not only irrelevant but insulting to those who aren't from whatever you consider industrialised - and if that's every country today, then it's doubly pointless.

Comment: @Nij , what bit you? That's not what he wrote, and it's also not what a reasonable reader would understand. The point is that the OP couldn't be bothered to add a country tag (even after being asked to), and it makes little sense to answer for 183 countries seperately, when all but the US and _potentially_ another one have the same rules. If he is from that potential country, and says so, we will gladly help him, but otherwise it is not useful to put effort in adding details relevant for 0.00001% of the potential readers.